# Counting the repetition of each rows separately in dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe

I have the following code for cleaning my data:

```
 val customSchema = StructType(Array(
      StructField("time_stamp_0", StringType, true),
      StructField("sender_ip_1", StringType, true),
      StructField("receiver_ip_2", StringType, true)))

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////make train dataframe
    val Dstream_Train = sc.textFile("/Users/saeedtkh/Desktop/sharedsaeed/dataset3.txt")

    val Row_Dstream_Train = Dstream_Train.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => {

      val array1 = array(0).trim.split("IP")
      val array2 = array1(1).split(">")
      val array3 = array2(1).split(":")

      val first = Try(array1(0).trim) getOrElse ""
      val second = Try(array2(0).trim) getOrElse ""
      val third = Try(array3(0)) getOrElse ""

      Row.fromSeq(Seq(first, second, third))
    })
    val Frist_Dataframe = session.createDataFrame(Row_Dstream_Train, customSchema)

    val columns1and2 = Window.partitionBy("sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2") // <-- matches groupBy

    ///I add count to the dataframe
    val Dataframe_addcount = Frist_Dataframe.withColumn("count", count($"receiver_ip_2") over columns1and2).distinct()
   // Dataframe.show()
    val final_add_count_attack = Dataframe_addcount.withColumn("attack", when($"count" > 10 , 0).otherwise(1))
```

The outpout of my code is the following dataframe:

```
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
|   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|attack|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
|06:10:55.881073|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881095|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881114|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881133|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881152|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881172|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881191|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881210|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881229|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881249|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881268|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881287|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881306|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881325|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881344|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881363|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881386|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   88|     0|
|06:10:55.881401|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.2|   85|     0|
|06:10:55.881424|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.2|   85|     0|
|06:10:55.881440|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.2|   85|     0|
+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
```

My problem is that I need to manipulate this code:  `val Dataframe_addcount = Frist_Dataframe.withColumn("count", count($"receiver_ip_2") over columns1and2).distinct()` among my code in such a way that, instead of having the total number of all rows for each row, it shows the count until that row. For example instead of having 88 for all in the dataframe, I need to have some thing like this. (This example is just for  first 20 rows)

```
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
    |   time_stamp_0|sender_ip_1|receiver_ip_2|count|attack|
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
    |06:10:55.881073|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   1 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881095|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   2 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881114|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   3 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881133|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   4 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881152|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   5 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881172|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   6 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881191|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   7 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881210|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   8 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881229|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   9 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881249|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   10|     0|
    |06:10:55.881268|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   11|     0|
    |06:10:55.881287|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   12|     0|
    |06:10:55.881306|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   13|     0|
    |06:10:55.881325|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   14|     0|
    |06:10:55.881344|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   15|     0|
    |06:10:55.881363|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   16|     0|
    |06:10:55.881386|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   17|     0|
    |06:10:55.881401|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   1 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881424|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   2 |     0|
    |06:10:55.881440|   10.0.0.3|     10.0.0.1|   3 |     0|
    +---------------+-----------+-------------+-----+------+
```

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had to use `rank` function for the `window` function which would give serial numbers for the *rows* in the *window*. But for this you need to order the `dataframe`.

Following changes should be enough for your requirements

```
val columns1and2 = Window.partitionBy("sender_ip_1", "receiver_ip_2").orderBy("time_stamp_0") // <-- matches groupBy

val Dataframe_addcount = Frist_Dataframe.withColumn("count", rank() over columns1and2).distinct()
```

The rest of the codes are same as yours. Hope the answer is helpful.